# Quartz.Net Job with multiple levels of DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, quartz.net

I have a `JobFactory : IJobFactory` that works. I can create scheduled jobs just fine, and inject simple dependencies with no problem, but I do have a problem with one issue. One of the dependencies *itself* depends on `HttpClient`, but that doesn't seem to work.

E.g.

```
services.AddHttpClient<Dependency>("dependency");
services.AddSingleton(typeof(Dependency));

using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
  var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
  var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
  scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactory(serviceProvider);
  await scheduler.Start();

  var job = JobBuilder.Create<Job1>()
                .WithIdentity("job1")
                .Build();
  var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();
  await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

with dependency constructor being

```
public Dependency(HttpClient httpClient)
{
  // <snipped>
}
```

and job constructor being

```
public Job1(Dependency dependency)
{
  // <snipped>
}
```

When I try to run this, I'm told the job is throwing an unhandled exception. Debugging through my JobFactory tells me that httpClient isn't getting injected at all. Shouldn't .AddHttpClient be handling this? Does it not work because of the multiple levels of DI? Is it possible to do another way?

Note, I attempted to also manually register `Job1` like I did `Dependency`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why did you add the singleton?

Comment: @Nkosi, I added the singleton so that it would be injected into `Job1`'s constructor when `Job1` gets scheduled.

Comment: Is this for web or console application?

Comment: Console application, but it just runs on its own, passing information between different services. There's little-to-no UI.

Comment: Ok then I'll have to change up my answer a little as I thought this was hosted in a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had three separate and unrelated problems simultaneously:

1. `AddHttpClient<Dependency>()` registers my dependency, and I shouldn't also include `AddSingleton<Dependency>()`.
2. I needed to register the job itself: `services.AddScoped<Job1>();` (thank you, @Nkosi)
3. My job had an `internal` constructor. It needed to be `public`. (Possibly because `static async Task Main(string[] args)` is static, but I'm uncertain.)

Answer (score 2):

This code is ripe for a refactoring.

Put the scheduler in a `IHostedService` and let that handle the start of the scheduler.

```
public interface IHostedService {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Triggered when the application host is ready to start the service.
    Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
    Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class SchedulerService : IHostedService {
    readonly IJobFactory jobFactory;
    readonly ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory
    IScheduler  scheduler;

    public SchedulerService(IJobFactory jobFactory, ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory) {
        this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
        this.schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Job1>()
            .WithIdentity("job1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger  trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        await scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return scheduler.Shutdown(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

With that out of the way, now the configuration can be done cleanly at startup by adding all the types to the service collection

```
class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        //...

        services.AddHttpClient<IDependency, Dependency>();
        services.AddScoped<Job1>();
        services.AddTransient<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>();
        services.AddTransient<IJobFactory>(serviceProvider => new JobFactory(serviceProvider)); 
        services.AddTransient<IHostedService, SchedulerService>();

        //...

        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var service = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostedService>(); 
        await service.StartAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

So now the service will manage the startup and also all necessary dependencies will get injected as needed.

Including your Typed Client `Dependency` class
assuming the following

```
public class Dependency : IDependency {

    public Dependency(HttpClient httpClient) {
      // <snipped>
    }
}

public class Job1: IJob {
    public Job1(IDependency dependency) {
      // <snipped>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this was helpful. I had two unrelated problems three separate problems. Your solution helped me realize that I needed `services.AddScoped<Job1>();`.